# Dom parser and Google image results

Tags: php, dom

I am trying to retrieve Google image results/links with php dom parser. The code I have just written run without error, but I do not see any results( i.e. links) outputting to my browser. Can you help me find out the problem? I cannot figure out.

Here is my script:

```
<?php
    include_once __DIR__.'/simple_html_dom.php';

    $name = '"michael jackson"';
    $query = urlencode($name); 
    $url = "https://www.google.com/search?q={$query}&tbm=isch&tbs=ic:color,isz:lt,islt:4mp,itp:face,isg:to";

    // Create DOM from URL or file
    $html = file_get_html($url);

    // Find all images
    $linkObjs = $html->find("div[class=rg_di rg_el ivg-i] a");
    foreach ($linkObjs as $linkObj) {
        $link = trim($linkObj->href);
        echo $link . '<br>';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get a different DOM structure in the browser (processed) than the one you get as plain html. Output the content of $html and you will see. You need to adapt your selector.

Comment: Excellent. Glad to help.